# Getting title of youtube videos using php domdocument

Tags: php, youtube, domdocument

I have a function that gets the title from a HTML source (I curl it first then pass the source to this):

```
function get_dom_page_title($source){
    $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $doc->formatOutput = false;
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $doc->strictErrorChecking = false; 
    @$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $source);

    $title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;

    if ($title !== ""){
        return (string)$title;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

However when I type in a youtube link`http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFeE4q4-M0o`, the title returned is all weird: `â€ªArsenal vs Benfica FT Highlightsâ€¬â€ - YouTube`, or `\n \u202aArsenal vs Benfica FT Highlights\u202c\u200f\n - YouTube\n`.

How can I sort this?

Comment: You'd need to have the script output in UTF-8 as well - a simple `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` might fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Code:

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html = file_get_html('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFeE4q4-M0o');
$title = $html->getElementsByTagName("title")->innertext;
echo preg_replace('/&#x([0-9a-f]+);/ei', 'chr(hexdec("$1"))', $title)
```

will output *Arsenal vs Merdosos FT Highlights,‏ - YouTube

**PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser** means less code and consistent results :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same thing with DOMDocument

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFeE4q4-M0o'));
$t = $doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue;
print_r($t);
```

Using DOMDocument means faster DOM processing compared to Simple.